# Should I mention conducting training programs in my Statement of Purpose for PhD admission?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I have conducted two hands-on training programs. I cannot decide whether or not I should mention this training experience in my SOP. I have quite a few publications, some conference papers, and 2 years of research experience. Will the addition of conducting the training programs as a "teaching" experience give my SOP more weight or should I avoid it?

The training courses were 1 month long each. Please provide any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What were you trained in in the training programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should base sharing this information on whether or not this information would be useful and showcase you as a strong candidate in what program you're seeking admittance. For example, if teaching is not a major or strong component of this program, you might not share it. If sharing this information will make you a strong candidate, then you should.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse your CV with your SoP. The statement of purpose should be about the future. What are your goals and how do you propose to achieve them? To some extent, you can mention past work, but only if it points to likely success in meeting those goals. I doubt this will help support your work as a researcher, which is the immediate short term goal.

I assume you don't want to run training classes as a career, so the information, which might be listed *somewhere* is better left out of the SoP so that you can stress more relevant things.

---

In the CV you might have a section for "service" or for "teaching related activities".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion....